# Laravel Submit Button Form does nothing

Tags: laravel

when I click my submit button and nothing happens, just the address changed, what should I check? please help?

view.blade.php

```html
        @if(Auth::user()->id !== $data->id)
        <form action="/send/{{$data->id}}" method="POST">
            <div class="card-body bg-light">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>

            </div>
        </form>
        @endif
```

web.php

```html
Route::post('/send/{id}', 'UserController@send');
```

UserController.php

```html
    public function send(Request $request, $profile_id){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'message' =>'required', 
        ]);

        $current_user = Auth::user();
        $newMsg = new inbox();
        $newMsg->senderID = $current_user->id;
        $newMsg->receiveID = $profile_id;
        $newMsg->message = $request->message;

        $newMsg->save();

        return redirect("/profile-user/{$profile_id}")->with("response", "Message sent Successfully");
        
    }
```

Comment: Please can you **edit** your question and copy and paste the code you have rather than using images.

Comment: @Tsuyoikin you form action and route is not matched

Comment: @Rwd done, I arleady edit it

Comment: @KamleshPaul its should be $data->id too?

Comment: @Tsuyoikin yes check you if contiion is ture or false

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Form Url  and also check you  url is exist

```
 @if(Auth::user()->id !== $data->id)
        <form action="{{url('/send/'.$data->id}}" method="POST">
            <div class="card-body bg-light">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>

            </div>
        </form>
        @endif
```

Comment: its still stuck there, does nothing

Comment: Check your Form url using inspect   && Also check if you have two <form> then  it will also create the issue  .Print Your $request data before validation

Comment: YUP THATS THE PROBLEM!
I have form inside form
THANKYOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Welcome brother

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
@if(Auth::user()->id != $data->id)
        <form action="{{url('/send/'.$data->id}}" method="POST">
            <div class="card-body bg-light">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>

            </div>
        </form>
        @endif
```

Use `!=` not `!==`

may be `$data->id` it contain string datatype so don't use `!==`

only use  `!==` when you are sure both are  same type

ref link https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

---

and you `/send/{{$data->id}}` also wrong use `{{url('/send/'.$data->id}}`

Comment: ok thanks for your information, but its still does nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to validate the csrf token which one is missing in 
your form.. Try it sure it will work
  @if(Auth::user()->id !== $data->id)
       <form action="/send/{{$data->id}}" 
   method="POST">@csrf
           <div class="card-body bg-light">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" 
  rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
               </div>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
```

primary">Send Message

```
           </div>
       </form>
       @endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Your textarea must refer the form it belongs to

```
<form id="my_form" ... >
    <textarea form="my_form" ... ></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: still does nothing sir, any another solution?